Distribution of a product of random variables
I have two independent distributions $X$ and $Y$. $X$ is defined by the piecewise CDF
$$F_X(x) = \begin{cases}
F_X^1(x) & x \in (-\infty, a_1)\\
F_X^2(x) & x \in [a_1, a_2)\\
F_X^3(x) & x \in [a_2, \infty)
\end{cases}$$
and PDF
$$f_X(x) = \begin{cases}
f_X^1(x) & x \in (-\infty, a_1)\\
f_X^2(x) & x \in [a_1, a_2)\\
f_X^3(x) & x \in [a_2, \infty)
\end{cases}$$
and Y is defined by the piecewise CDF
$$F_{Y}(y) = \begin{cases}
F_Y^1(y) & y<0\\
F_Y^2(y) & y\geq0
\end{cases}$$
and PDF
$$f_{Y}(y) = \begin{cases}
f_Y^1(y) & y<0\\
f_Y^2(y) & y\geq0
\end{cases}$$
What is the CDF and PDF of $Z = Xe^Y$?

I've tried to break the problem down using the Law of Total Probability (I omitted some terms below), but I get stuck at the last step. I don't know how to convert this to an integral with the right bounds.
\begin{align*}\mathbb{P}(Z<z)    &=\mathbb{P}(Xe^{Y}<z) \\
    &=\mathbb{P}(X<ze^{-Y}) \\
    &=\mathbb{P}(X<ze^{-Y},ze^{-Y} < a_{1})+\mathbb{P}(X<ze^{-Y},a_{1} \leq ze^{-Y} < a_{2})+\dots\\
    &=\mathbb{P}(X<ze^{-Y},\ln(z)-\ln\left(a_{1}\right) \leq Y) \\
    &\qquad+\mathbb{P}(X<ze^{-Y},\ln(z)-\ln\left(a_{2}\right) < Y \leq \ln(z)-\ln\left(a_{1}\right))+\dots \\
    &=\mathbb{P}(X<ze^{-Y},\ln(z)-\ln\left(a_{1}\right) \leq Y,Y<0) \\
    &\qquad+\mathbb{P}(X<ze^{-Y},\ln(z)-\ln\left(a_{1}\right) \leq Y,Y\geq0)+\dots \end{align*}

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent you have to state that explicitly.

@geetha290krm Thanks for letting me know; I edited the question to include that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

I would try to use rules for the PDFs of sums and products of random variables. First, to get the one for $e^Y$ in terms of its power series and then for $Z = X*(e^Y)$. Involves convolution, etc.

CDF: Use Bayes' rule to obtain
\begin{align}
& \mathsf{P}(Xe^Y \le z)\\
= & \int \mathsf{P}(X \le e^{-y}z \mid Y = y) f_Y(y) \mathrm{d}y \\
\overset{\text{indep.}}{=} & \int \mathsf{P}(X \le e^{-y}z) f_Y(y) \mathrm{d}y \\
= & \int F_X (e^{-y}z) f_Y(y) \mathrm{d}y~. \\
\end{align}
Note that it's better to condition on $Y$ (rather than $X$) as $e^Y$ is positive.
PDF:
You can now differentiate the above w.r.t. $z$ to get the density.
If $f_X$ is continuous, you can use Leibniz's rule to push the differentiation under the integral sign, i.e., differentiate $F_X (e^{-y}z)$ w.r.t. $z$ (and get $f_X (e^{-y}z)e^{-y}$).
In that case,
$$f_Z(z) = \int f_X (e^{-y}z) e^{-y} f_Y(y) \mathrm{d}y~.$$

That's called the law of total probability, not Bayes' rule.

What would I use for $F_X(e^{-y}z)$ under the integral given that $F_X$ is a piecewise function?

You first split the integral as $\int\limits_{y<0}+\int\limits_{y \ge 0}$. Then for each term, you split further into three parts {$(-\infty,a_1),[a_1,a_2),[a_2,\infty)$} depending on the value of $e^{-y}z$.
